Story about mass hibernation "time travel" to a future that is worse than the present
I've read the story in a translation, so it was likely originally published in English before 1972.
The protagonist works for a police department that detects and wakes up "sleepers", who try to hibernate through the current bad times to a bright future. He decides that he as well is tired of that present time and because he was capturing other sleepers, he successfully hides and wakes up in 20 years or so. However, the world is even worse, one of the highlights that when he went to sleep auto-driving was a norm, while in his new old job his partner is excited that soon a pilot run of a self-driving car will happen.

Ah, when you said "worse", I was half expecting the sleepers to wake up to find that food was short, and they were only being revived because freezer burned meat tasted horrible...

Not that much worse :) but the idea you've mentioned was among stories is one of J.J.Adams post-apoc anthologies

Larry Niven has an in-universe Known Space reference about the "Sleeper Kids", idealistic young people that saw cryogenic suspension as their path to a brighter future.  After several decades in cold sleep they were declared dead and broken up for spare parts.
